# Displaying the date correctly

Tags: php, svn, datetime

I have a folder ( i mean a project)which is connected the server  (svn)

my requirement is to show the svn updation number and the updated date, in a page

$info = @file('.svn/entries');
then i displaying the  values from the the array $info

echo $info[9] should come 2010-01-11T06:21:33.250281Z.But the date is comming a another date 2010-01-08T10:15:24.920971Z

i donot get the reason, please help me

the contents in in the file '.svn/entries' is

```
9

dir
2585
http://linto/svn/boats/trunk
http://linto:8080/svn/boats



2010-01-11T06:21:33.250281Z
2585
stefan
has-props

svn:special svn:externals svn:needs-lock











7cfa2e9e-4e07-4858-8dae-0f23e53ec418

tmp
dir

tests
dir

application
dir

database
dir

htdocs
dir

library
dir

logs
dir

bin
dir

zend_config.php
file




2009-11-10T11:12:01.000000Z
3bc0c01861134dc7691a5f3c14e7f449
2009-11-10T10:19:52.004372Z
2254
kai





















937

README
file




2009-11-02T04:52:20.000000Z
c207747d5c69969a9663d7438cf46c84
2009-10-02T08:49:00.954220Z
1869
root





















216
```

Comment: I've tried your code and this file, entries, and when i output info[9] i get the result: string(28) "2010-01-11T06:21:33.250281Z"

Answer (score 0):

My guess is: You're reading the wrong file.

```
$path = '.svn/entries';
echo '<pre>Debug: current working directory is ', htmlspecialchars(getcwd()), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: reading ', htmlspecialchars(realpath($path)), "</pre>\n";
$info = @file($path); 
echo $info[9];
```

Comment: That's my conclusion as well.